# Voice, What voice type am I a Bass Baritone, a Baritone, a Tenor, an Alto, a Soprano, a conta tenor?

Tags: voice

My chest voice range is B flat 1 to E5 on a good day F5.   I can sing in all this range.  My falsetto goes to at least F6.   I get requests to sing using all my range.  I will be 83 February 27,2022.   I have a medical problem which stopped me from singing for about 50 years.  I now control my problem with diet.  I started learning how to sing February 2019.  At that time the highest chest voice note was D4.  I am a ringer at the Bebop Boston (night club in Boston,next to Berkley Music School).  Every Thursday night they have an (open?) mic.  I am always the first performer.  I sing 2 songs.  My second song is My Way.  I bring down the house every time.  I make mistakes but most people do not notice.  Last night I sang.

Comment: Four and a half octaves!?

Comment: And all in chest voice? Are you sure you aren't mixing up the upper portions of that range with your head voice?

Comment: _If_ the range in the question is accurate, the "duplicates" aren't particularly helpful.

Comment: Yes my range is  over 4 1/2 octaves but the highest chest notes need work but they are improving.  I am open to sing anything in any voice range.

Comment: The detail in this question shouldn't matter even if it's accurate as the OP is asking to put their range into one of the groups listed which is why it's a duplicate of what the typical ranges are. If they don't fit in that's fine, but so could many, many other singers and it wouldn't be good to just allow this question infinitely. If the question was instead flipped to just be about terminology for when a range doesn't fit that would make more sense.